# Display the message for wrong command line string in win32

Tags: c, shell, winapi, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have the following code which calls two different function as per the command line string entered from the command line. My application name is minopc.exe

so when user enters the following code in command prompt

```
minopc.exe -regserver 

srv.GBRegisterServer is called .
```

and when user enters the following code in command prompt

```
minopc.exe -unregserver 

srv.GBUnRegisterServer is called .
```

The code is

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    TCHAR *cmd_line = GetCommandLine();
    TCHAR *token;
    if ( (token = strchr(cmd_line, L'-')) == NULL ) token = strchr(cmd_line, L'/');
    if (token)
    {
         token++;
         if ( !lstrcmpi(token, LPCSTR("regserver")) || !lstrcmpi(token, LPCSTR("r")) )
         {
              srv.GBRegisterServer(&guid, L"WesOPC", L"WesOPC Server", L"WesOPC.Sample.MinOPC", L"1.0");
              return 0;
         }
         if ( !lstrcmpi(token, LPCSTR("unregserver")) || !lstrcmpi(token, LPCSTR("u")) )
         {
               srv.GBUnregisterServer(&guid);
               return 0;
         }
    }
```

Now i want to display the error if the user enter other thing beside minopc.exe -regserver and minopc.exe -unregserver . But it is accepting other commands and even running the program when written like minopc.exe -a etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't do any error handling, so any other paramter is accepted. What you have to do is

```
if ( lstrcmpi(token, LPCSTR("regserver")) || lstrcmpi(token, LPCSTR("r")) )
{
    srv.GBRegisterServer(&guid, L"WesOPC", L"WesOPC Server", L"WesOPC.Sample.MinOPC", L"1.0");
    return 0;
}
else if ( lstrcmpi(token, LPCSTR("unregserver")) || lstrcmpi(token, LPCSTR("u")) )
{
    srv.GBUnregisterServer(&guid);
    return 0;
}
else
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid argument\n");
    return 10;
}
```

Comment: can you give me some idea regarding error handling for command line string. and how to display the error message in command prompt

Comment: I want to display the message in same command prompt from where we fire the command such as     minopc.exe -regserver .

Comment: What is the linker setting? If there is something like `CONSOLE` then use `fprintf(stderr...)` because that would be the correct thing. If it says `WINDOWS` you don't have a console window, even if you started the program from a command prompt.